# How do I connect my delphi client to a server over the internet using indy?

Tags: delphi, client-server, delphi-7, indy

I have a delphi application (made in delphi 7) using the indy components. I can connect them both locally and they both transfer data just fine etc. Now I would like to host my delphi application on a server over the internet. What would be required to do this? What kind of server would I need and how would they connect to each other?

Comment: Be aware of the security implications of having a server directly accessible over the Internet.

Comment: If you only open up this port and you have a proprietary protocol you will be fine. However, if you use DMZ like most SOHO installations (a few machines sharing an internet connection), then of course all port traffic will now be sent to one machine.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to have nothing to do with Indy or Delphi at all.

To connect to a server on the internet, you need a server on the internet.  That is to say, you would need a PC running windows, that has a publically available IP address, or one of the following:

1. A VPN that allows you to dial in to a private network.   A Vpn would provide you with a lot more security than you would get putting your windows PC/server machine directly onto the internet with a public IP.
2. A hosted machine, somewhere with a fast internet connection, usually located at an ISP (called co-location), or a "cloud instance" (a virtual machine hosted by a major "cloud hosting" provider such as Amazon EC2 or Windows Azure).  Note that Delphi XE has some special features for working with Cloud computing (Azure and Amazon).   You can get such services all over the place and then you will have a server machine with a fast internet connection, which you can do whatever you want with, including installing your server software.  This costs money, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the server PC is exposed on the Internet so that the client PC can see it, and the client and server software should work exactly like they do when running on the same PC.

If your server computer has a [non routable IP address](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_nonroutable_IP_address) that can't be seen from the Internet, you will have to get some help from your router.  For example, have any connect requests on a certain port redirected to the internal IP address of your server PC.

Comment: Also a VPN can be used, the VPN server will perform the routing (authorizing and protecting the traffic also)

Comment: Or any method that allows the client PC to see or otherwise communicate with the server PC with which it is trying to connect.